# Compilation error when standalone is used together with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: standalone, tikz-external, scrlayer-scrpage

**Major edit to clarify my intentions** (Original question at the bottom)

I have three documents:

(1) The custom class:

```
%myclass.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

% myclass is based on scrreprt
\LoadClass{scrreprt}

% load some packages of which only 
% scrlayer-scrpage is important for this MWE
\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

% and the others just serve as examples
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

% define some commands / settings used throughout 
% a document written in this class
\definecolor{mycolour}{RGB}{255, 0, 0}
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textcolor{mycolour}{\textbf{#1}}}

\endinput
```

(2) The side document:

```
%sidedoc.tex
\documentclass[class=myclass]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, fill=mycolour] {dummy};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(3) The main document:

```
%maindoc.tex
\documentclass{myclass}

\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
    This is a \emph{useless} emphasis.

    \includestandalone{sidedoc}
\end{document}
```

I'm embedding the side document (2) into the main document (3) to obtain a PDF for both. I'm loading `myclass` (1) as option in the side document (2) in order to have access to defined commands and settings. In my example this means having access to `mycolour`. Unfortunately this also loads `scrlayer-scrpage`, which is the root of a compilation error.

If I compile the main document (3) everything works as expected:

[image: maindoc]

If I compile the side document (2) the following error is thrown

> Arithmetic Overflow. [...] I can't evaluate this expression, since the result is out of range.

which points to `\end{document}`. Yet, the PDF is also correctly produced:

[image: sidedoc]

Is their a way to overcome this?

---

If the side document (2) only contains a `tikz` picture, TeXnician proposed in a comment to utilise the `tikz-external` library. This circumvents the `standalone` package and therefore also the compilation error.

---

**Original Question**

I have written a custom class `myclass`, which is based on `scrreprt`. Among other packages `myclass` loads `scrlayer-scrpage`. I want to embed TikZ graphics into my main document with the `standalone` package. Within the standalone document I'm loading `myclass` as an option of the `standalone` class. I'm doing this to have access to all the settings and commands defined in `myclass`.

MWE of a 'standalone' document with the same behaviour:

```
% \documentclass[class=myclass]{standalone} -> actual code
\documentclass[class=scrreprt]{standalone}
% within the actual code the next line is included in myclass.cls
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw] {dummy};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The compilation with `pdflatex` fails with

> Arithmetic Overflow. [...] I can't evaluate this expression, since the result is out of range.

and points to `\end{document}`.

Is there an option / way I have missed to overcome this?

---

This is more of an inconvenience rather than a problem, since ...

1. ... this problem only occurs if I compile the 'standalone' document. If embedded in the main document everything works fine.
2. ... the PDF is, as far as I can tell, correctly produced regardless of the errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Another approach: Use TikZ's externalization feature, which also produces the standalone graphics.

Comment: @TeXnician If I understand the `external` library correct, its purpose is to generate an standalone pdf file from the TikZ picture. I use the `standalone` package mostly for two reasons: 1. Convenient 'drawing' of the picture without sorrounding content. 2. Convenient import with `\includestandalone[options]{...}`, which lets me manipulate the size etc. of the picture within my main document. If the `external` library can do this, can you please provide a MWE?

Comment: Well for (1) that's a question of habits (sometimes I even have a document with identical preamble somewhere just to test figures and then copy the code into the real-world document). Concerning (2) of course it is easy to manipulate it, because you have all options of a tikzpicture (e.g. scale) and the exported image is a PDF, so you have it as a separate file. The big advantage, however, is that external obeys your preamble settings and loaded packages.

Comment: For some reason it is trying to create a footer.  I can't imagine why you would want to use a KOMA specific feature inside a standalone anyway.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Is it possible to prevent it from trying to do so? I'm not trying to utilise this feature within the standalone. It is part of my custom class, which I'm loading as parameter.

Comment: @JohnKormylo If I understand you correctly, you are saying that one loads the target class in the options of the standalone document in order to have access to settings and commands of the target class. If that is the case, that is exactly what I want to do. I edited my question to clear up my intentions.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't know where you getting at. How are the settings I defined in the custom class relevant to the compilation error, if they are definetily not causing the problem? Since you seem to insist on an example: I defined a custom colour palette, which I'm using for highlights throughout the document as well as in TikZ pictures. As stated, this works well and causes no problems. I could have even left the TikZ out of the MWE, since it is also not the root of the error. In that case @TeXnician could have not pointed me towards `tikz-external`, so it was not useless afterall.

Comment: So you want to load a custom document class in order to use the color definitions. Fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned off KOMA footer.

```
\documentclass[class=scrreprt]{standalone}
% within the actual code the next line is included in myclass.cls
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\makeatletter
\let\@oddfoot\relax
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw] {dummy};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that I want to load `scrlayer-scrpage` while not using it. This is not the case. It is loaded as part of my custom class, which I load to have access to its commands and settings in order to keep the style of the main and side document consistent. I have rewritten my question to clear up my intentions.